# Confuse array element address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I expect to see p and &atbl[1] print the same value (location of element 1) but it differs

```
struct a {
    unsigned int  el[4];
};

struct a atbl[3] = {
  {0x12131415, 0x01030507, 0x01030507, 0x16171819},
  {0xa2a3a4a5, 0x02020202, 0x02020202, 0xa6a7a8a9},
  {0xb2c3d4e5, 0x02020202, 0x02020202, 0x0badcafe},
};  

struct a * p;
// read address of element 1 in atbl
p = (atbl  + (1 * sizeof(struct a)));
printf("%08x %08x %08x %08x %08x\n", p, atbl, &atbl[0], &atbl[1], &atbl[2]);
```

But I get the following results:

**p -   dae83240**
atbl    -   dae83140
&atbl[0] -   dae83140 
**&atbl[1]-  dae83150**
&atbl[2] - dae83160

Any hint ?

Comment: atbl is a pointer, so you are using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: For starters, the statement `p = (atbl  + (2 * sizeof(struct a)));` gets me an out of bounds pointer arithmetic error: 465 bytes (30 elements past end of array.

Comment: I am sorry I edited the p equation above, from 2 to 1.

Answer (score 4):

```
// read address of element 1 in atbl
p = (atbl  + (2 * sizeof(struct a)));
```

This should be:

```
p = atbl + 1;
```

Adding one to something that already points to the first entry will make it point to the second entry. So adding two would make it point to the third entry. You want it to point to the second entry, so you need to add one.

Also, you don't multiply by the size because the pointer already knows the size of the things it points to. Adding one already makes it point to the next object.

Comment: "the pointer already knows the size of the things it points to" Is it because my struct is only four unsigned int ? How about if it is a complex ADT ?

Comment: @AsamPadeh If the type is known, its size is known. Basically, you get the same thing you'd get if you did `sizeof (*atbl)`.

Comment: interesting, sizeof(*atbl). atbl itself is a pointer to a (i.e &atbl[0]) so sizeof(*atbl) is the size of the pointer? How can a pointer have size ?

Comment: @AsamPadeh Yes. `sizeof(*atbl)` is the size of what `atbl` points to. If that's a pointer (because `atbl` is a pointer to a pointer), then it's the size of that pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Pointer arithmetic automatically accounts for the size of the pointed-to object; you don't need to multiply by `sizeof(struct a)`.

`atbl`, after the implicit array-to-pointer conversion, is a pointer of type `struct a*`. `atbl + 2` points 2 `struct a` elements past the address that `atbl` points to.

Also, don't use `%x` to print pointer values; instead, cast the pointer value to `void*` and use `%p`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
p = (atbl  + (1 * sizeof(struct a)));
```

you need

```
p = (atbl  + 1 );
```

If the starting address of the struct `atbl` is `1000` (let's say) then adding `1` to it increment it by `16` units and `p` points to `1016`(assuming `4` bytes for `unsigned int`). It will not increment `p` by `1` unit (`1001`)
Also, you are using a wrong specifier to print address. This will invoke **undefined behavior**.

### C11: 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, **the behavior is undefined**.282) If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, **the behavior is
>   undefined**.

Use `%p` specifier to print address. Your `printf` statement should be like:

```
printf("%8p %8p %8p %8p %8p\n", (void *)p, (void *)atbl, (void *)&atbl[0], (void *)&atbl[1], (void *)&atbl[2]);
```

---

Suggested reading: [**Pointer Arithmetic**](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html).